# Java App Performance in Virtual Machine vs. Local Machine

Tags: java, performance, virtual-machine

I have this doubts about a Java application, this app was tested in 4 different places, 3 of them were Virtual Desktops, and 1 was a local computer, and was tested directly in eclipse and the jar. the time of execution in the 3 Virtual Desktop was the same (10 minutes) while in the Local Machine was at least 3 hours. I want to know if there is some way that being local or virtual could affect the performance of a Java application or is just that something is wrong in the local machine?

I hope I explained myself. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough detail to accurately answer. Perhaps the desktop machine has very little RAM, or one of its hard disks is failing, or the hard disks in the VM hypervisor are faster or...

Comment: Yes, there are numerous ways in which a virtual machine environment could produce performance differences relative to physical machine.  Most of them would be expected to favor the physical machine, but a few might go the other way.  Speculation about details would be pointless, as there are too many cases to consider.  Have you tried *profiling* your code?

Comment: Memory, certainly start it outside eclipse.

Comment: We can only speculate, because the physical machine is in another country, I can only work on virtual, so that's why I did not experienced the performance of the application on a physical machine. I think I will have to follow your suggestion @JohnBollinger

Comment: The client said that he recently changed his laptop, so, I do not think that the problem is the hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of factors that could influence performance. For example, we've run into issues with anti-virus software scanning all the JRE files each time the java command was run. I doubt that's your problem, but it points out all the variables you need to consider.